# Laravel 4 not refreshing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a strange issue in laravel 4 as each time I try to refresh the page changes doesn't appear . For sure it's not browser's cache . Any help appretiated

Comment: Post some information about the setup and bundles you are using.

Comment: Did you save you page before refreshing the browser ?  :)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issues and found an answer:

Try disabling OPcache in your php.ini

If you use MAMP, it can be found at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini

And dont forget to restart MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the back-button, finally i noticed, that in my Laravel project no `Cache-Control` header was sent. The browser decided to cache this page and didn't do a new request.

To send this header, you can modify the `app/filters.php` file like this:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
  $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried
- composer dump-autoload
and
- php artisan dump-autoload
From the document root ?

Comment: That doesn' t look like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the cache engine. If you updated via composer, try getting /app folder updates from github (especially config files), sometimes there are changes in files in that folder. You could also try to chmod 777 `storage` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes OPcache method isn't working, I use this code to make sure all changes are visible every time the page is loaded:

in `app/filters.php` add this in `App::before(function($request)`

```
$cachedViewsDirectory=app('path.storage').'/views/';
    $files = glob($cachedViewsDirectory.'*');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(is_file($file)) {
            if($file!='.gitignore') {
                @unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
```