# Laravel 5 - Class changes ignored

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

Bit of an odd one. Any changes I make to `Job` classes are ignored. Regardless of if I run `composer dump-autoload` and `artisan clear-compiled` etc. Going by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761984/laravel-4-not-refreshing), I've double checked that `OPcache` is disabled.

The only way I can get homestead to acknowledge the changes is to `halt` and `up` the box, which is obviously very time consuming.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

For completeness. I'm running homestead 0.2.6 on Windows 10. But it's never been a problem, until yesterday.