# LARAVEL error hljs is not defined in app_debug=false

Tags: javascript, laravel, debugging, referenceerror

When I disable the debugbar (barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), or I put `APP_DEBUG=false` in .env instead of `APP_DEBUG=true`, I have a error with a script for image gallery (baguetteBox).

The error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hljs is not defined at window.onload

If i not disable app_debug or debugbar, i'v not error and it's ok..
If i click on a image of my website with this error, it's bug and open image on page (in url: http://127.0.0.1/website/images/image.png), but if enable the app_debug or debugbar, image open in a "modal" of baguetteBox (normal).

Screenshot of my error:
[Uncaught ReferenceError: hljs is not defined at window.onload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCuHG.png)

Comment: Can you please expand the error in the console and take another screen shot? i.e. Click on the little arrow/caret.

Comment: `hljs` is referring to the `hightlight.js` package (https://highlightjs.org) used in DebugBar.

Comment: When i click on arrow of the error in console, it's write this: "window.onload @ 1?page=1:328"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When DebugBar is turned on, the library is loaded by DebugBar and `hljs` is defined. When DebugBar is turned off, `hljs` is not defined so the script breaks after `hljs.initHighlighting();`. Try this:

```
    if ( typeof oldIE === 'undefined' && Object.keys && typeof hljs !== 'undefined') {
        hljs.initHighlighting();
   }
```

Comment: The code in html inspector don't change .. Why ? I've try many browser(ie, edge, chrome)

Comment: You'll need to speak with a developer. You need to make the change in your source code, not in the browser.

Comment: I changed in my code source but, when inscpect my page with inspector, the code of the script not change

Comment: Here are some things you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761984/laravel-4-not-refreshing

Comment: No worries, emeliku!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that.

```
const hljs = require('highlight.js');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => {
      hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```